# How to change the color of separator dots in ModernCV?

Tags: header-footer, titles, moderncv

I want to change the color of the separator dots to the theme color of the CV. When I use normal color theme like `\moderncvtheme[orange]{casual}` I am getting the dot in grey color like the one in pic 1 in the image below. What need to be done to change it so that it will be in line to the color of the theme as in pic 2. Can anyone help?

[image: Picture that shows the difference]

Comment: For future reference, please consider including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than code snippets.

Comment: sure.. I will do that..

Answer (score 6):

The symbol used to separate fields in the footer is controlled by `\footersymbol` which is defined in the `casual` theme as

```
\newcommand*{\footersymbol}{{~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}
```

If you want the symbol to adapt to the color theme chosen, you need to redefine it to use a bullet in the `color1` color:

```
\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{{~~~{\rmfamily\textcolor{color1}{\textbullet}}~~~}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[orange]{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{{~~~{\rmfamily\textcolor{color1}{\textbullet}}~~~}} 

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{The title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works.. Thank you very much for the quick help